# Force a subclass to override both methods or none

Tags: java

Say I have a base class with a pair of methods (called `foo` and `bar`). In most cases, they don't need to be overriden, but in some cases, they do. I want to make sure if one of them is overriden, then the other one must also be overriden, or it is an error.

What tricks could I use to ensure either none of the two methods is overriden, or both of them are overriden?

Comment: You cant force users to do this, you could only document it, if they do not do it then its their fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has proven to be an interesting thought exercise. The best solution I could come up with is as follows:

Declare an interface for your methods:

```
public interface YourInterface {
  public void methodOne();  
  public void methodTwo();
}
```

Create a base class that implements these methods by delegating to an inner `YourInterface` instance. Take a parameter in your protected constructor that overrides the default behaviour:

```
public abstract class Base implements YourInterface {

  private YourInterface override;

  protected Base(YourInterface override) {
    this.override = (override == null) ? new BaseImplementation() : override;
  }

  @Override
  public final void methodOne() {
    override.methodOne();
  }

  @Override
  public final void methodTwo() {
    override.methodTwo();
  }

  // This is the default implementation
  private static class BaseImplementation implements YourInterface {

    @Override
    public void methodOne() {
      System.out.println("Original one.");      
    }

    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {
      System.out.println("Original two.");
    }    
  }
}
```

The two methods are `final` in the base class, so subclasses can't just override one of them.

Not necessarily an elegant or advisable solution.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting trick. It didn't directly solve my problem, because what I have is an existing abstract class, to which I'd like to add the two methods in question. But this did give me ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. A method exists, but I don't know if it will really meet your needs. I think what you should really consider is *why* you want this, and if a different construct (abstract classes? AOP? Something else?) will meet your design needs better.

You can write a snippet to quickly determine if a method has been overridden:

`String declaredIn = obj.getMethod("myMethod").getDeclaringClass();`

This will return the current class name if overridden, or a/the base class name if not.

If you require any subclasses to call `super.foo` and `super.bar` in `foo` and `bar` (which you can enforce with stuff like non-parameterless constructors), you can enforce this in the base methods: check if the declaring class is the same for both methods, and throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem exists in [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), with the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods.

If you want to absolutely ensure that an implementation is provided for either both or neither, [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500259/836214) provides an elegant solution for this by wrapping the functionality in an interface to be passed in during construction - it guarantees either the default implementation for both methods, or a different implementation for both.

However, if your case is more like the one in `Object`, where they dont' **need** to be overridden, but just satisfy a very specific contract, then clear documentation on what that contract is will work better, allowing developers to satisfy the contract the way they determine is best.

Answer (score 0):

If you had one method and you wanted to make sure it was overridden, I think something like this would work:

```
public class C {
    public void foo() {
        if (this.getClass() != C.class)
            throw new RuntimeException ("foo was not overridden for class " + this.getClass().getName());
...
```

But making sure two methods are either both overridden or not overridden seems much trickier.  How about this: Instead of having child classes override `foo` and `bar`, make `foo` and `bar` `final` methods, and provide protected "implementation" methods in which classes must override either both or neither.  Then:

```
public class C {

    private boolean fooCalled = false;
    private boolean barCalled = false;
    private boolean fooDefault = false;
    private boolean barDefault = false;

    public final void foo() {
        fooCalled = true;
        fooImpl();
        checkOverrides();
    }

    public final void bar() {
        barCalled = true;
        barImpl();
        checkOverrides();
    }

    private void checkOverrides() {
        if (this.getClass() != C.class && fooCalled && barCalled && 
            (fooDefault != barDefault)) 
            throw new RuntimeException ("foo or bar was overridden without the other for class " + this.getClass().getName();
    }

    protected void fooImpl() {
        fooDefault = true;
        // the rest of the default implementation
    }

    protected void barImpl() {
        barDefault = true;
        // the rest of the default implementation
    }

}
```

We can't check until both `foo` and `bar` have been called at least once each (and if either of those is never called, then it shouldn't matter whether it's overridden or not).  Once both have been called, we will know whether or not each method (the "Impl" version) was overridden, because a flag will be set when the default implementation is called.  Then we can do whatever checking we wish with the information.

This will fail if an overriding `fooImpl` calls `super.fooImpl()` (similarly for `bar`), but my guess is that if you expect this to happen, then the requirement that both be overridden if one is probably doesn't make sense.  If it's still necessary, a separate `protected` default implementation method could be provided that doesn't set the `fooDefault` flag, and clients will just have to be careful to use it instead of the `super` method.

Having written all this, it's hard for me to imagine that a solution like this would be really necessary.  Maybe you have a case where it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a contructor to your class and use reflection to check in wich class the methods are overrided and throw an Error if it's only one overrided.

Can be something like this (test is the name of the base class that I used):

```
public test() {
    Class clazz = this.getClass();
    try {
        Method m = clazz.getMethod("foo", new Class[]{});
        Class cFoo = m.getDeclaringClass();
        m = clazz.getMethod("bar", new Class[]{});
        Class cBar = m.getDeclaringClass();
        if (cFoo.equals(test.class)&&!cBar.equals(test.class)) throw new Error();
        if (!cFoo.equals(test.class)&&cBar.equals(test.class)) throw new Error();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite handle the case where there is a deep tree of subclasses: `A -> B -> C`, where one is implemented in `B` and one is implemented in `C`, this test would incorrectly pass for class `C`. It's a nice start for an idea though.

Comment: Chris, you can chage the condition to if (!cFoo.equals(cBar)) throw new Error(); if you want to check that case

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a marker interface **@OverrideRequired** with target METHOD
2. Annotate needed methods with @OverrideRequired.
3. Use Reflection to write validateOverrideRequired(Class...classes) which throws a RuntimeException if the methods with annotations @OverrideRequired are not overridden in the subclass? Call it once per build as a rule.

The above is just a concept; not sure of the implementation.

But an interesting question & equally interesting answers (rest) from the group.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you put both of them into an interface and let the client decide whether to implement them or not.
This way either both of them are overridden if some implements this interface or not if no one implements

Comment: It sounds like the classes in question should inherit default behaviour for these methods. So your solution wouldn't really work, as the base class would already implement this interface.

Comment: Yes @Duncan , But this will ensure that either both of the methods are implemented or not.

Comment: That is not what the OP wants. The OP wants to ensure both are *overriden* or not.